# I am getting errors when I try to install ruby for the first time. I am on macOS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, macos-high-sierra

```
Jeffreys-MacBook-Air:~ Jeffrey$ rvm install 2.3
ruby-2.3.4 - #removing src/ruby-2.3.4..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/ruby-2.3.4.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more 
information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx_brew.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' is already up to 
date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4, 
this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.4 - #downloading ruby-2.3.4, this may take a while depending on 
your connection...
ruby-2.3.4 - #extracting ruby-2.3.4 to /Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/src/ruby- 
2.3.4....
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch 
/Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/patches/ruby/ruby_2_3_gcc7.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch 
/Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.4/fix_rb_thread_fd_close.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - #applying patch 
/Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.3.4/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.3.4 - 
#configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.3.4 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.3.4 - 
#compiling........................................................|
ruby-2.3.4 - #installing........
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/log/1528602254_ruby-2.3.4/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the 
installation.
```

Where can I find the install log? I tried looking in the finder but I was unsuccessful. I'm following the installfest I found on the Odin Project if that helps at all.

Comment: 3rd line from the bottom clearly says: `/Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/log/1528602254_ruby-2.3.4/install.log`.

Comment: The location of the install log is listed in the output above.  But as it is in a Directory that starts with a dot (.) it is hidden from both finder and normal ls commands.  You can cd into .rvm and then then type ‘open .’  To open the directory in finder

Comment: `cat /Users/Jeffrey/.rvm/log/1528602254_ruby-2.3.4/install.log`

Comment: I was able to open the install log. I have absolutely no clue what anything means. I don't understand it all.

Comment: if you can't understand them, you can share the log here so that experts can help you understand the case.

Comment: You could try installing the Ruby through `brew`. Also I've found `rbenv` to be more problem free than `rvm` in macOS.